# AWS-SDK 2.x is not working for Node 20 and 21

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

I am using aws-sdk 2.x.
I export AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG like this `process.env.AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG = 1;`

I have a basic class

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
let client;

class SecretManager {
  constructor() {
    throw new Error("Constructor not implemented");
  }

  static initialize(config) {
    AWS.config.update({
      region: config.aws.region,
    });

    client = new AWS.SecretsManager();
    return client;
  }

  static getClient() {
    return client;
  }
}

module.exports = SecretManager;
```

using it like this.

```
const secretManager = SecretManager.initialize(config);
secretManager.getSecretValue(
  { SecretId: config.awsSecretManagerId }, () => {}
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
I am facing an awkward issue. I tried to run my project with node 20 but the AWS Secret is getting timeout. It is working fine with node 18 and node 19. I am using nvm to do the switching.
```

I am facing an awkward issue. I tried to run my project with node 20 but the AWS Secret is getting timeout. It is working fine with node 18 and node 19. I am using nvm to do the switching. My project is originally node 12.
Also, whenever I switch the node, I clean package-lock.json and node_modules, do a `npm i` and then run the project. I have also tried otherwise, e.g. do an npm i with node 12 and switch to node 20, same error. I did `npm i` at node 20 switch to node 18, it worked.